# how to get the selected color

Tags: reactjs, color-picker

I used colorPickr to build three color select components. The problem is that I can't find the variable that stores the selected color in order to use it and store it into the state..

I tried to use the event "save" that is mentionned in the documentation :  https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr

```
export default class ColorPicker extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
        const pickr = Pickr.create({
            el: '.color-picker',
            theme: 'classic',
            swatches: [
                'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
                'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
                'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
                'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
                'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
                'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
                'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
                'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
                'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
                'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
                'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
                'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
                'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
                'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
            ],

            components: {

                // Main components
                preview: true,
                opacity: true,
                hue: true,

                // Input / output Options
                interaction: {
                    hex: false,
                    rgba: false,
                    hsla: false,
                    hsva: true,
                    cmyk: false,
                    input: true,
                    clear: true,
                    save: true
                }
            }
        });

    }


    render(){

        return(

        <Fragment>
        <div  className="color-picker"></div>


        </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use events. For example:

```
pickr.on('save', (color, instance) => {
    console.log('save', color, instance)
});
```

Comment: could you tell me how and where to use it please. I new to react and its way of handling events. thank you

Comment: it will be boring. Instead of trying to implement JS colorpicker, try to use special component for react https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/